# Proper way to evaluate booleans in if else statements

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, boolean

Sorry in advance if this has been answered somewhere, but I did look around for a while and didn't find anything.

I'm coding in Objective-C, but this is mostly a general coding question. I'm essentially wondering if there is a proper, professional way to write if else statements involving booleans. Specifically, I would like to know if

1. There is a "fastest" "best" coding practice for the ordering of if else statments involving booleans
2. Is there a more aesthetically popular way of writing them?

So, for example, here are three different ways I'm wondering about

**Method 1**

```
if (myBool)
{
    //Do something
}
else
{
    //Do something else
}
```

**Method 2**

```
if (myBool)
{
    //Do something
}
else if (!myBool)
{
    //Do something else
}
```

**Method 3**

```
if (myBool)
{
    //Do something
}
if (!myBool)
{
    //Do something else
}
```

I know this sounds kinda dumb and is really harping on subtle details. I'm mostly wondering about these different methods in terms of code readability. It almost seems like **method 2/3** is best to me in terms of readability. This allows you to search for specific cases of that variable, which might be easier in large files. Maybe this is a minute point, and really doesn't matter though.

Method 1 seems like the most common to me, and is what I would pick by default. But for more experienced coders out there, is there a specific way to do this, or just preference?

Comment: if you are working with bool, you should avoid 2 & 3 at all cost. User method1 always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1. There is a "fastest" "best" coding practice for the ordering of if else statments involving booleans***

> "Put the case you normally expect to process first. This is in line with the general principle of putting code that results from a decision as close as possible to the decision...[putting the normal case after the if] puts the focus on reading the main flow rather than on wading through the exceptional cases, so the code is easier to read overall."

[Code Complete](http://www.cc2e.com/), 2nd Edition, pages 356-357.

***2. Is there a more aesthetically popular way of writing them?***

In normal logic flow it is better to use **Method 1**

Comment: Your quote applies to all options …

Answer (score 0):

One thing to take into consideration is the values you are expecting.

In this case, boolean only has **two** possible values, and therefore makes sense if we use Method 1 as the most "convenient" way.

Method 2 works effectively when you have more than 2 possible values to be checked.

Method 3 on the other hand is convenient when value of **myBool** may change after the first [if] condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think Method1 is common and efficient also.
1. In method3 if myBool is true then there is no need of checking 2nd if condition.
2. In method2  there is no need of 2nd if because bool have only 2 values either it is yes/true or no/false. Use else if only there are more than 2 cases.
3. When you are using if else or if else if you should provide condition according to probability. Means condition which satisfied most must be placed first.

Answer (score 0):

A neat way of doing if/else for very simple assignments

```
int num;
if (isNegative) {
    num = -1;
} else {
    num = 1;
}
```

Short hand would be:

```
int num = isNegative ? -1 : 1;    //   -->   condition ? true : false
```

I wouldn't suggest this for complex conditions/assignments as can get messy. But I've found it useful for compacting very simple if/else assignments.